# Combine bootstrap rows on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a easy way to combine two rows in bootstrap with jquery based off user actions?

In my app the user moves a slide bar and i want the 4x4 grid to turn  into 3x3 grid. Hers how I'm re sizing my columns.

[image]

[image]

I cant figure out how to properly reconfigure the rows.  I'm hoping there something out there i missed that does this for me.

```
$slider.slider({
          max: 80,
          step: 20,
          min:0,
          value:0,
          orientation: 'horizontal',
          range: 'min',
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
                if(ui.value < 20){
                  $(".cellsize").removeClass("col-md-4");
                  $(".cellsize").addClass("col-md-3");
                  $(".cellbutton").removeClass("btn-lg").addClass("btn-sm");

                }else if(ui.value >= 20 && ui.value < 40){

                  $(".cellbutton").removeClass("btn-sm").addClass("btn-md").removeClass("btn-lg");
                  $(".cellsize").removeClass("col-md-3");
                  $(".cellsize").addClass("col-md-4");
                  $(".cellsize").removeClass("col-md-5");
                }else if(ui.value >= 40 && ui.value < 60){
                   $(".rowcell2").addClass("row")
                    $(".rowcell").removeClass("row")
                  $(".cellbutton").removeClass("btn-md").addClass("btn-lg").removeClass("btn-block");
                  $(".cellsize").removeClass("col-md-4");
                  $(".cellsize").addClass("col-md-5");
                  $(".cellsize").removeClass("col-md-6");
                }else if (ui.value >=60 && ui.value < 80){
                  $(".cellbutton").removeClass("btn-lg").addClass("btn-block");
                   $(".cellsize").removeClass("col-md-5");
                   $(".cellsize").addClass("col-md-6")
                   $(".cellsize").removeClass("col-md-12");
                }else{
                   $(".cellsize").addClass("col-md-12")
                   $(".cellsize").removeClass("col-md-6");

                }
              }
        }).addSliderSegments();
```

My attempts so far have to been to try to  delete rows depending on the current size of the columns.

Update With html, I'm using django template language.  I can post it the html printed if needed.

```
           <div class = "col-md-12">
                            {% for card in cards %}
                                {%if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4%}
                                      {%if forloop.counter0 != 0%}
                                           </div>
                                       {%endif%}
                                       <div class = "row">
                                {% endif %}
                                <div class = " cellsize col-md-3 ">
                                  <div id =  "cell{{card.id}}">
                                    <ul class="list-group   " id = "cellwidth{{card.id}}">
                                        <!--- ommited --->

                                    </ul>
                                  </div>
                                </div>                                  
                            {%endfor%}
```

`

Comment: if you turn a 4x4 grid into 3x3, you now have nine items instead of 16 - which ones do you want to be shown in that case?  the first 9? or should it actually just go from 4 x 'n'  to 3 x 'n' and still show all the items?  Also, please post your HTML - it's somewhat a guessing game to suggest modified JS without knowing the HTML structure.

Comment: Sorry instead of 4x4 i ment 4 x n to 3 x n

Comment: so, is the second image above the desired result (every 4th item in a new row, aligned right)? or do you prefer that when you change the setting you have everything in full rows of three (first row is items 1,2,3 - next row is 4,5,6 etc.)?

Comment: No the second image is the current result.  I want everything in full rows of 4, 3 ,2 or 1 depending on the location of the slider.

Comment: cool - working on a quick codepen for you that might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do this using Bootstrap.  You'd have to write custom logic yourself, which really isn't worth it considering there's several libraries out there that already do this very well.  You should check out something like [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) or [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), both of which I've used in the past and would do exactly what you want with only a few lines of JavaScript.

Comment: Call me crazy, but the question has been here for 20 minutes and already the accepted answer is that it can't be done?  Yikes...

Comment: It's not that it can't be done; it's that it can't be done with default Bootstrap.  This type of responsiveness is not supported by Bootstrap's grid system.  The OP can definitely write custom JS code to do this, but there's numerous free libraries already available that do exactly what the OP wants/needs, which have already been extensively tested.

Comment: I don't disagree there are tools out there for this, but without the details of what the desired result is or even knowing the HTML structure, it just seems a premature conclusion.  Why not explore it a little more before jumping into an additional library?  Totally possible I'll end up completely agreeing with you - but then again, maybe there's more to it :-)

Comment: The HTML structure is completely irrelevant to the question. The OP wants to change how many items are in a row in Bootstrap given a certain screen size.  This is simply not supported in Bootstrap.  Whether the OP provides an example HTML page or not won't change this.  The OP also clearly explained what their desired result is.  I must be misunderstanding something.  Can you please explain what's unclear to you?

Comment: I'm not looking for a debate - sorry if something I said came across as argumentative...I simply believed that having more info might actually lead to a solution the OP finds preferable to adding an additional library.  Maybe it did, and maybe not, just trying to be helpful to the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to have 'full' rows at each re-sizing based on the bootstrap class you are adding and removing, perhaps you don't actually need all the rows to be wrapped in a bootstrap row (`<div class="row">` isn't necessarily required to have a row visually.)

Here's a codepen that illustrates this behavior when re-sizing the screen (taking advantage of bootstraps grid and media queries): http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVQbKm

It sounds like you want to have the user set the number of columns, and while that's not bootstrap default behavior, it looks like you are ok with adding/removing the classes to do it, and you have the right idea that changing from col-md-3 to col-md-4 would indeed change the items from being 4 across to being 3 across.  So it may be that what you have will work fine if you just wrap all the items in a single bootstrap row and let the width of the items dictate how many fit in a visual row, since they will naturally flow down when space isn't available.

Without seeing the HTML, it's hard to say if your jQuery is going to work exactly as is, but if it doesn't feel free to add a codepen of your own along with any explanation of what's not working - happy to take a look.

Comment: This is what I would do as well. Unless there is something else happening that requires each set of columns to actually be in rows, you can simply wrap 8 or 12 or whatever column elements in a single .row container and then change the col-md-4 to col-md-3 and back. Issues typically arise when you have columns with different heights, in which case you may be better off using masonry or another library to handle the grid for this section. If all items are of equal height or you can define the height of each column, this will work fine.

Comment: I'm' experimenting with this post's tips.  Each cell has a responsive image so the heights slightly vary.  If the heights are a problem would another solution be to scale the image down and make each cell a fixed height?

Comment: Are the columns just an image? Or image with text underneath? If just an image, I would change the image to a div, give that div a height that is approximately the same ratio as the original image, and apply the image via background-image with a background-size of cover. This will eradicate any tiny differences in height, giving it a clean look, and eliminating the height issues.

Comment: Unfortunately its image with text underneath, but the text is a fixed height. So that might work.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: scaling the images would be an option, yes - I was assuming based on your images, which looked like everything was equal size, and didn't account for varying heights.  assuming you're setting the images to `max-width:100%` and the heights are then depending on the image ratio, you could 1) make the images the same h/w ratio  2) set a height on the div containing the image and add `overflow:hidden` - this hides the portion of the image that is too tall. or 3) make the images a background as Taylor suggests.  I'm sure their are more options...all depends on how your context and your end goal.